# Parts of my text disappears!

Tags: errors, compiling

I am using WinEdt 10 (64 bit). Today, I observed a strange behavior that I cannot understand. I would appreciate if anyone could explain why parts of my text would disappear due to a grammatical error in my text!

When I compile my text that has a grammatical error at the end of the last sentence, parts of my text disappears in the output pdf (the figure below shows a snapshot of my latex file with a duplicate word "to" at the end and its pdf output which is missing parts of its second line):
[image]

[image]

When I fix the grammatical error by deleting the duplicate word "to", the disappeared part shows up! Can anyone understand why winedt/latex behaves this way?

[image]

[image]

For clarification: Lines in pdf snapshots are end-of-page and header lines, so they are not parts of the text.

Comment: Can you make this happen with only that paragraph in question, plus a few packages?  Could you paste that corresponding tex code, instead of giving us screen shots?

Comment: When I delete any other parts of the text, this does not happen! So I couldn't produce what you ask.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Can you compile your document using command line, instead of WinEdt? Is the result the same?

Comment: What did you do to  get wjnedt to underline the grammatical problem?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Repetead words are underlined by default.

Comment: @Arzigoglu Ah right. Never really realized this. Well we will need the actually code to test this.

Comment: @RobtAll I am using PDFTeXify. I do not know how to compile the document using the command line. I would appreciate if you could give me a step-by-step instructions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately, I cannot upload the whole paper and when I try to shorten the paper to include only the problematic part, the problem goes away; i.e. when there is a change in the document, the sentence does not disappear. I assume it has something to do with optimizing the length of each line and positioning each paragraph that Latex does in the background.

Comment: Try this: Open a Windows command prompt (some people call it a "DOS box"). Type `pdflatex -v` and see the result. Assuming it is found: Navigate to the folder containing your tex document. Then type: `pdflatex yourfilename.tex` modified for your file name. Works better if no spaces in file name. Does that compile as expected? If it does, then the problem is with WinEdit. But if you see the same problem, then the problem is with your TeX code. Note: Use `xelatex` or `lualatex` as compiler, if necessary.

Comment: @RobtAll Thanks for the instruction. I followed the instruction and produced a pdf file, but the file does not include references---I tried to compile the document several times to make sure that all required files are produced. The produced pdf includes all my sentences; however, I do not think that I can conclude that the problem is with WinEdt, because as the references are not produced, so the whole paper is a bit shorter, and words and paragraphs are not in their original places.

Comment: @amir In a Windows command Prompt, after running `pdflatex yourfilename.tex` run `bibtex yourfilename` and then again `pdflatex yourfilename.tex` twice, so to have your references compiled.

Comment: @Arzigoglu Thank you! Now, I've got my references back. As I guessed, now that everything is back, the sentence disappears again.

Comment: @amir so WinEdt is not the source of the problem, as I guessed. Do you have an up-to-date TeX system (TeX Live or MiKTeX)? If not, try updating it.

Comment: Did you ever find out what's the problem? I got it and can't figure out what is going on. This must be the most ridiculous bug I've seen with LaTeX so far! I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.5700 on Win7 and it's impossible to find a MWE. Only a document that has the same exact spacing causes MiKTeX to fail; it outputs a line with only the first word, and the rest of the line seems to have vanished far to the right beyond the page margin.

Comment: No, I could not figure out the reason. I had to change the spacing a bit to avoid that. But now, whenever I create a pdf I visually go through that to make sure nothing is left out---very frustrating!

Comment: I got that frustrating problem again, and believe it might be due to the `footmisc` package with the `hang` option interacting in some weird way with the `hyperref` package. Any ideas or work-around that you found in the past 2 years?

Comment: I give up; the bug is sensitive to the number of pages (even though there is a manual page-break before the issue, removing earlier pages causes the bug to vanish).

Comment: @user21820 Unfortunately, I do not have my latex file that had this reported issue. If you do not mind, you can send your instance to me that I can share it here. If people see an example, they might be able to help us better.

Comment: Sorry I can't share my source file. I did something that appears to fix it in my case; I removed the `hang` option from `footmisc` and replaced it with my own code: `\makeatletter\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\setlength{\hangindent}{\footnotemargin}\noindent\rlap{\@makefnmark}\rule[0em]{\footnotemargin}{0em}#1}\makeatother`. Do you remember whether you also used `\footmisc` with `hang`? If so, then maybe this is the answer.

Comment: I had the exact same problem in my document and [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422089/parts-of-my-text-disappears#comment1081814_422089) to this question contained a "solution" which "solved" the problem for me. 
Could the question be reopened so that the comment can be added as an answer for future readers?

Comment: Is there any message in the log file?

Comment: I have not explored the log file, but I can say that there is no clear sign of this happening unless you read the output.

Comment: I just got the bug again, this time despite not using the `hang` option of `footmisc`. I am using the `article` class with font size `11`, and found that changing `\setlength\footnotemargin{1em}` to `\setlength\footnotemargin{11pt}` resolved the bug, so I am very sure the bug is related to footnotes...

Comment: Do you think you could post a MWE, as a code block rather than an image, that reproduces this bug? Without that, it’s impossible to test.

Comment: My last comment above was kind of wrong; I got the bug again and found that I can solve the bug by [making a change that is supposed to be completely free of side effects](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422089/parts-of-my-text-disappears#comment1578821_599714)! It is possible that footnote packages use some obscure LaTeX internals that triggers an overflow bug under rather rare circumstances, which is somehow tied to the internals of `\setlength`. Therefore, ironically, we can 'fix' the bug by just adding `\newlength{\fixmissingtext}\setlength{\fixmissingtext}{1em}` to the preamble!!

Comment: In the end, I fixed the problem by completely dropping the `footmisc` package. After all, I was only using the `bottom` and `hang` options. These can be imitated using the `etoolbox` package via `\pretocmd{\footnoterule}{\vfill}{}{}` and the code I provided above. Sigh. DIY seems best.

Comment: I am sad to say that despite not using `footmisc` or `fancyhdr` or any footnote-related package, the bug has returned. This is getting increasingly annoying as I have ≈ 200 pages and it is ridiculous if I have to check every single page every time I make a change...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in my document (and sadly also cannot upload a MWE) and "solved" it as suggested by [Salivan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/33653/salivan) in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422089/parts-of-my-text-disappears#comment1081814_422089):

### Change the spacing a little

Even though it is not a real solution, but only fights the symptoms, it was the only way I could get a correct PDF.

In my case it was enough to replace `:`  (colon, space) by `:\`  (colon, backslash, space) in the document, which changes the spacing only very little.

### Details

For anyone interested in the problem, I put my preamble here. I removed all lines, where I'm 100% sure, that they're not related to the problem, like `\newcommand`, `\tikzstyle`, ... .
Since the problem disappears with the slightest change, the preamble is still quite large.

As described in the preamble, commenting out the line `\newcounter{unusedCounter}` "resolves" the problem. The counter is nowhere else used in the code.

The compilation log-file in the buggy case shows for the last counter of the bibtex-part:
`\c@cbx@tempcntd=\count512`

Maybe someone has an idea, whether this could mean something. I mean, a high powers of 2 that appears at the same time as a problem could very well be related to that problem. Still, I changed some other lines that led to a compilation where also `\c@cbx@tempcntd=\count512`, but the pdf-output was correct.

The preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, cleardoublepage=plain, openright, hyphens]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, ngerman, main=english, australian]{babel}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,circuits.logic.US,positioning,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\pageeq}[2]{\ifthenelse{\pageref{#1}=\pageref{#2}}{p.~\pageref{#1}}{pp.~\pageref{#1}-\pageref{#2}}}
\newcommand{\Pageeq}[2]{\ifthenelse{\pageref{#1}=\pageref{#2}}{Page~\pageref{#1}}{Pages~\pageref{#1}-\pageref{#2}}}

\let\newclassictheorem\newtheorem 
\let\classicproof\proof

\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
            (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
            (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
    },
    L/.style={thmbox, 
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);},
    },
    LQ/.style={thmbox, 
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
    },
}


\newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-LF}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\newclassictheorem{hypothesis}[]{Hypothesis}

\newtcbtheorem[number within = section]{theobox}{Theorem}{thmbox,L, 
    before skip=1em plus 0.5em,
    after skip=1em plus 0.5em}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=theobox]{defbox}{Definition}{thmbox,L, description delimiters parenthesis, separator sign none, 
    before skip=1em plus 0.5em,
    after skip=1em plus 0.5em,
fontupper=\normalfont}{def}
%% Many more \newtcbtheorem[use counter from=theobox] 
\newtcbtheorem[]{proofbox}{Proof}{thmbox,LQ,
    before skip=1em plus 0.5em,
    after skip=1em plus 0.5em}{proof}

\newcommand{\thmCounter}{tcb@cnt@theobox}

\newclassictheorem{algo}[\thmCounter]{Algorithm}
\newclassictheorem{algo-sketch}[\thmCounter]{Algorithm Sketch}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thesection.\arabic{\thmCounter}} 
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{\thmCounter} 
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% % Comment the following line out to dissolve problem
\newcounter{unusedCounter}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ieee,
sorting=nyt,
bibencoding=utf8,
defernumbers=true,
maxnames=10,
citestyle=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}

\assignrefcontextkeyws[labelprefix=J]{J}
\assignrefcontextkeyws[labelprefix=C]{C}
\assignrefcontextkeyws[labelprefix=B]{B}
\assignrefcontextkeyws[labelprefix=W]{W}

% Pseudo-Code
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

% \hyphenation, \newcommand, \tikzstyle, ...
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: No, please, this isn't a solution and shouldn't be treated as one! Can you confirm whether you are using `footmisc` or not?

Comment: @user21820 This isn't a great solution, but it does solve the problem.  So until someone can reproduce the problem and is willing to share that example with the rest of us, "change the spacing a little" is the best that we'll get.

Comment: do you still have a sample document that shows this behaviour?

Comment: @user21820 Sorry for the late reply. As you can see now, I did not use `footmisc`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I still have the file, also sorry for taking so long to reply. I tried working it down to an MWE, but even removing an unused counter "resolved" the problem. (See the added preamble in m answer).

Comment: @Rayllum I assume that if adjusting the preamble causes the change, then adjusting the text also causes the change.  Are you able to add enough text so that something in the source file disappears before reaching the pdf?  Ideally, you'd find a working example, even if it's not minimal.

Comment: Without any MWE that reproduces this bug, I’m afraid there’s not much I can do for either you or the original asker. All I know is that there’s some document that has it.

Comment: @Rayllum: Wait so do you have an example (no need to post it) that does *not* use `footmisc` but *has* the bug?

Comment: @Rayllum you still have not provided an example of the problem so it's impossible to even guess an answer sorry. You need to provide a test document not a preamble that shoiws no problem. It doesn't have to be long (you can probably delete most of the preamble) but it does need to be an example of the problem.

Comment: @Teepeemm Your assumption is right. Weirdly enough, for some cases even removing text on a page far before the disappearing text (including many `\clearpage`s inbetween) resolves the problem. Sorry, I don't understand your question; what do you mean by "before reaching the pdf"?

Comment: @user21820 Yes, exactly. I use another footnote-related-package: `fancyhdr`

Comment: I'd really like to provide a MWE, but I cannot since after only little changes the problem disappears. Thus, I cannot delete enough of the non-publishable text.
As a LaTeX-non-expert I still provide the information I have, because maybe there's a way I didn't think of to find the cause of the problem. Like a compilation in some sort of debug-mode.

Comment: Text disappearing between the tex source code and the resulting pdf would be a serious bug, which is why the topic gets such attention.  But if the only thing users finding this bug can tell us is "it sometimes happens", then that's not enough for us to even start.

Comment: @Teepeemm I think I understand you now, you were asking me to add text to the preamble. I'm sure I wouldn't be successful, since I couldn't even work my way from the problematic file to a MWE, sorry.
I thought about showing (a limited audience) via ScreenShare what happens, but I don't think any knowledge can be gained from it.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Does it help if I believe that the bug is caused by a really fat box that gets inserted after the first word on the line, which pushes everything else off the page to the right? What I cannot fathom is how a footnote-related package can do that even when there is no footnote on that page.

Comment: @Rayllum: I am completely guessing in the dark, but I think that this bug is caused by some deeply embedded overflow bug, because the bug just popped up again for me and I found that merely adding or removing a `\setlength` of a completely unused length can fix it!! This should **not** even change the spacing, nor any bit of the layout, but somehow has an effect!

Comment: @user21820 I agree. For me, commenting out an unused counter, which also has no impact on the spacing, "resolved" the problem. Moreover, the counter has "number" 512, which is a high power of 2, indicating an overflow problem. If wish there was a way to see intermediate steps of the latex compilation...

Comment: @Rayllum There is a way to see intermediate steps, and lots of people are really interested in seeing this bug.  But it requires someone to post (anywhere) a complete example.  We've already established that whatever is happening is sensitive to the smallest change, so just the preamble is insufficient.

Comment: @Teepeemm: I am unable to get a working example that does not have personal identifying information. Even changing the title causes the bug to disappear! One day, when I have nothing to do, I will try to get an anonymous example. But right now, that's kind of impossible.

Comment: @Teepeemm What is this way to see intermediate steps?

Comment: @user21820  I have the same problem and I had multiple of such days. But I can only change so little before the bug disappears, that the document still has over 100 pages full of content that I cannot upload.

Comment: @Rayllum you can always see the steps lax is taking add `\tracingall` at a suitable point

Comment: After discussion with *Ulrike Fischer* and *David Carlisle* and *Joseph Wright* in chat, I discovered that LyX was somehow the culprit. When I compiled the same LaTeX source file using TeXworks instead of LyX (using the same pdflatex and the same MikTeX installation) and the bug was fixed (everything looks identical except the missing text appears). Are you also using LyX? I'm guessing it's a difference in command-line options but I don't know what command LyX runs. CC @Teepeemm

Comment: My comment above is wrong. LyX was not the culprit. It was simply that TeXworks had an extra `synctex=1` command-line option. Although the bug vanished upon turning that option on, I can't tell whether it is just luck (since changing almost anything destroys the bug anyway). But [showoutput is identical except for the synctex-related magic-markers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=60820976#60820976), down to the claimed resources used by TeX! So something is *deliberately adding* the "`, glue set < -20000.0`" (causing the bug) *after* the output routine. CC @Teepeemm

Comment: Also don't have a MWE but I have experienced the same behaviour in two column documents where several multi-line footnotes were being placed on the same page.  My workaround has been to use inline links to documents using \href to reduce the use of footnotes.  Maybe this can help someone.